# Argument for Static Method with private access

Tags: java, class, static

Why I must pass parameter to static Method with private access control in Java.

```java
class Test extends Teacher
{
  int field = 123;

  private static void accessInstance(Test test)
  {
    System.out.println(test);
  }
}
```

For the below code it *generates error*

```java
  private static void accessInstance()
  {
     System.out.println("Hi there");
  }
```

Comment: Where did you get that idea?

Comment: It is hard to understand your question - both examples compile...

Comment: your compiler is kidding you. it doesn't give errors.

Comment: Post a stacktrace with the exact error...

Comment: "Why I must " You dont need to.

Comment: How can you inherit from a final class `Math`?

Comment: As of community consensus above, -1

Comment: Math is declared final but i guess it was just a bad example.

Comment: -1 because *searching for the error message* would have revealed many duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler will give you an error if your class is inner class and is not static, e.g.:

```
class X
{
    class Test
    {
        int field = 123;

        private static void accessInstance(Test test)
        {
            System.out.println(test);
        }
    }
}
```

This will work if the inner class is static:

```
 class X
{
    static class Test
    {
        int field = 123;

        private static void accessInstance(Test test)
        {
            System.out.println(test);
        }
    }
}
```

You should correct your post I think.

A static inner class means you can instantiate it without having an instance of an enclosing outer class instance.

> JLS 8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances
>
> Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are constant
>   variables (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Because the static methods can't access instances values, just static values. So if you want a static method to access values of field of an instance you must pass it as a parameter.

In the end you'd better think of make the method not static so that you can call it directly from on instance object.

Besides, there is nothing wrong (at least that would make it not compile) with the code above.